# How to scan barcode in salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, tooling-api

Overall task is scan the barcode in saledforce.

Suppose my computer is connect with barcode scanner machine.

In salesforece  i've a custom object ITEM.  create a visualforce page of this item object and when we  click on new button the vf page will display.
we can scan the barcode then barcode id should be display on the page in row.
and finally when we click on saved button then record will be saved

this is possible or not? or something i'm going in wrong way.

If possible. How to achieve overall this functionality.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I have actually written a barcode scanner page a few years ago in Visualforce.

## The Scanner

Set the scanner to Keyboard Mode. This varies by model. Make sure you also configure a scan termination code, which is usually either 8 (tab) or 13 (enter). This may be a file on the scanner, or might be set by scanning configuration bar codes. If you can't set the keyboard mode or scan termination code, you're going to find it hard/impossible to use.

## The Input

Write a small JavaScript function for the keydown event on your input element, and then cancel the default action when your scan termination code comes across. From there, instead call an actionFunction to update the view state of the page.

---

Included is a very rough POC to get you started. This code should work on modern browsers. You could also use your favorite JavaScript framework to implement this behavior as well.

---

```
public class scannerController {
    public String[] codes { get; set; }
    public transient String code { get; set; }

    public scannerController() {
        codes = new String[0];
    }
    public void addCode() {
        codes.add(code);
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="scannerController">
    <apex:form>
        <script>
        (function() {
            "use strict";
            window.addEventListener(
                "load",
                function() {
                    var input = document.getElementById("scanner");
                    input.addEventListener(
                        "keydown",
                        function(event) {
                            if(event.keyCode !== 13) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            event.preventDefault();
                            window.addACode(event.target.value);
                            event.target.value = '';
                            return false;
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        })();
        </script>
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!addCode}" name="addACode" reRender="output">
            <apex:param name="code" assignTo="{!code}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <input id="scanner" />
        <apex:dataTable id="output" value="{!codes}" var="item">
            <apex:column title="Codes" value="{!item}" />
        </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, Thanx for your help. suppose i connect barcode machine and press enter so can it automaticlly read in vf page? no need of any integration. another is i'm not aware of how to keep scanner in keybord mode. so is any study doc for this available Please share

Comment: @Amol I had a [Motorola CS3000](http://www.barcodehub.com/motorola-cs3000-batch-scanner.html) (or similar, I forget the exact model, since it's been a few years). The scanner would stay in keyboard mode until it was explicitly changed, and the scan termination code was configured to LF (13), so you could scan many codes without the need for any keyboard interaction. My solution was more complicated, because it could also count quantities, and would group like items together, but the code I've included in this answer should work at a basic level. Try it out. No additional software was needed.

Comment: @Amol I don't have that code any more, plus it was fairly specialized and had hundreds or so lines of code. While I'm not adverse to trying to answer messages by email, things sometimes slip through the cracks, so I would also suggest asking your questions here on SFSE. The main reason this question is attracting close votes is because it it's not a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Once you have enough code that's mostly right, but doesn't work for whatever reason, you can ask those questions here. My email's on my profile, just click on my name.